# Understanding the Definition of a Rank-1 Tensor

Tags: definition, tensors, tensor-rank, tensor-decomposition

A tensor is nothing but a multidimensional array. We can think of  an $n-mode$ tensor as a structure whose each element has to be referred with the help of $n$ indices or $n$ axes.

Now, while reading [this paper,](https://www.kolda.net/publication/TensorReview.pdf) I found a section titled as, rank $1$ tensors on page number-4.

But I seem to be a little bit confused, for I don't understand if I got that concept correctly or not. This is the precise reasoning I thought of creating the post to write out my understanding and seek validations for it's correctness.

It seems that the author says, that first we assume that say, we have $n-$ distinct axes for our reference and say, we have, an $n-mode$ tensor $X$ in $R^{I_1\times I_2\times\cdots \times I_n}.$ Furthermore,  $n$ vectors $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ are aligned in each of those $n-$ axes. We denote the $jth$ element of a vector $v_i$ as $a_i^{(j)}.$

Now, if each element of an $n-mode$ tensor, say, $x_{i_1i_2...i_n}$ is the product of the corresponding elements of those $n-$ vectors with respect to equal indices, i.e $$x_{i_1i_2...i_n}=a_{i_1}^{(1)}a_{i_2}^{(2)}\cdots a_{i_n}^{(n)}$$ then we call, $X$ as a *Rank-1* tensor and use, the notation, $X=v_1\circ v_2\circ\cdots\circ v_n.$

Now, I want to know, whether I got this correctly? Any help regarding  this apparent issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a good example how even a super-pedagogical paper can be confusing. Don't mix up the axes in **Fig. 2.1** with the vectors $a,b,c$ in **Fig. 2.3**. The author deliberately called those axes *fibers*. They are not vectors, in contrast to $a,b,c\,.$ I also have to say that (the author) calling a tensor $X=v_1\circ v_2$ *Rank*-1 is not standard. Likewise the notation $\circ$. It is usually $\otimes\,.$ Read on and make the best out of that paper.

Comment: @KurtG. Ok, but what about my understanding? Is it correct? I mean I can proceed if and only if I am sure that I got this part correctly :)

Comment: Is my inference in line with the paper?

Comment: I disagree with this thinking multiple times. Neither want to ponder about that paper, nor about your inference. Press on and practice. Skip stuff that sounds weird to you. Grab the meat. If you don't like that paper look for another one.

Comment: @KurtG. I don't know, but I really like that strategy! I will think my inference is good to go and proceed. Let's see what happens...